# Keys of unordered_map

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map

What kind of restrictions are there on the datatype of key and value when constructing an unordered_map in C++11?

I tried to create this:

```
unordered_map<vector<int>, int>
```

This gave me a compilation error. Do I need to write my own hasher?

Comment: @MarcoA. I also want to find out "when" to write a custom hasher.

Comment: When you have a type for which it isn't defined or unless you're not satisfied (for whatever reason) with the default one

Comment: @MarcoA. How do I find out the types for which it isn't defined? I couldn't find a comprehensive list of basic types anywhere.

Comment: This is a _good_ question, and it is not the same as asking "how do I define a custom hash function for `unordered_map`?"

Answer (score 3):

[`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)'s keys need a hash implementation by specialising [`std::hash`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash).

The standard specializations for basic types which are defined in the STL are:

```
template<> struct hash<bool>;
template<> struct hash<char>;
template<> struct hash<signed char>;
template<> struct hash<unsigned char>;
template<> struct hash<char16_t>;
template<> struct hash<char32_t>;
template<> struct hash<wchar_t>;
template<> struct hash<short>;
template<> struct hash<unsigned short>;
template<> struct hash<int>;
template<> struct hash<unsigned int>;
template<> struct hash<long>;
template<> struct hash<long long>;
template<> struct hash<unsigned long>;
template<> struct hash<unsigned long long>;
template<> struct hash<float>;
template<> struct hash<double>;
template<> struct hash<long double>;
template< class T > struct hash<T*>;
```

For everything else you need to write your own hash and/or use [`boost::hash`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/hash.html).

Furthermore as [Tony D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/410767/tony-d)'s comment says:

> You can specify the hash function as a third template parameter if you
>   prefer. Separately, operator== must also be available for the key objects, or
>   comparison specified as a fourth template parameter.

Comment: +1 for some useful information, but "by specialising `std::hash`" isn't quite true, as you can specify the hash function as a third template parameter if you prefer.  Separately, `==` must also be available for the key objects, or comparison specified as a fourth template parameter....